# How to combine ontotext GraphDB autocomplete and SPARQL to refine searching?

Tags: autocomplete, sparql, graphdb

I'm looking at this query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX ex: <https://example.org/>
SELECT distinct ?person
WHERE {GRAPH ex:someGraph 
      {
        
        ?name <http://www.ontotext.com/plugins/autocomplete#query> "bar".
        ?person ex:hasSibling ?sibling.
        ?sibling ex:name ?name .
    }
      }
```

as I want this to fetch the IRI of a person, who's sibling's name is somehow highly related to "bar".

If I remove `?person ex:hasSibling ?sibling` and `?sibling ex:name ?name` triples, and change `?name` to `?person` this works fine - I am returned all IRI's that have some indexed property containing the string "bar". Is it possible to further specify the IRI using other SPARQL statements? If so, what am I doing wrong in my syntax?

Comment: the autocomplete function returns resources that match the pattern. The important point is that it returns the resource IRIs, not the string being indexed. That means, in your query `?name` is a an IRI. If you want to restrict that to siblings then you should change the var name to `?sibling`. The idea behind is that you found resources matching "bar", and with the additional triple patterns your restrict the lookup to those being a sibling of some person

Comment: long story short `?sibling <http://www.ontotext.com/plugins/autocomplete#query> "bar".`

Comment: and it didn't work with your query because in the triple pattern `?sibling ex:name ?name .` the `?name` would probably just be a string literal, thus, it would never match the IRIs of the autocomplete lookup

Comment: I see, thanks for that, very clear.

Trying this: 
`?sibling <http://www.ontotext.com/plugins/autocomplete#query> "bar".`

should thus return the IRI of a sibling that has ex:name "barbara" indexed right?
(I tried that, it didn't return anything)
Could it be that the subject of <http://www.ontotext.com/plugins/autocomplete#query> cannot be a blank node? (this is why I was looking for the ?person ex:hasSibling ?sibling connection)